# не работает цикл и счетчик

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача состоит в том, чтобы считать количество введенных до того момента цифр пока пользователь не введет цифру 2. При вводе 2 просто печатает пробел

```
a = int(input())
b = 0
while a != 2:
    b += 1
    if a == 2:
        print(b)
```

Answer (score 5):

В вашем примере, при запуске скрипта, идет запрос на ввод числа пользователем, которое присваивается переменной `a`, а далее, в случае, если пользователь введет любое число не равное 2, начинается бесконечный цикл `while`, т.к. к примеру пользователь вводит `7`, цикл проверяет условие `7 != 2`, получает `True`, увеличивает `b` на единицу и далее снова цикл делает проверку `7 != 2`, ведь переменная `a` не менялась и по прежнему равно `7` и так бесконечно.

Вам нужно что-то типа такого:

```
a = b = 0
while a != 2:
  a = int(input('Введи число - '))
  b += 1
print(b)
```

Comment: если пользователь первым же числом введет `2`, то ваш код напишет `1`, а должно быть `0`. потому что ДО `2` он ввел `0 чисел/цифр`

Comment: @n1tr0xs, ну как мне показалось ТСу необходимо получить количество попыток (считать ДО тех пор, ПОКА не ввел цифру 2), за которые пользователь "угадал" число и соответственно, если пользователь сразу вводит 2, то он "угадал" с первого раза, по этому результатом и будет единица

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
b = 0
a = int(input('Введи число - '))
while a != 2:
    b += 1
    a = int(input('Введи число - '))
print(b)
```

Или можно так:

```
b = 0
while True:
    a = int(input('Введи число - '))
    if a == 2:
        break
    b += 1
print(b)
```

А можно использовать синтаксис из `Python 3.8` [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) :

```
b = 0
while a := int(input('Введи число - ')) != 2:
    b += 1
print(b)
```